# AWS RDS EBS Byte Balance constantly low, but burst balance and EBS IO Balance are always 100

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have an t4g.small RDS running Postgres. I seem to be constantly battling a low EBS Byte Balance (percent).  Burst balance and EBS IO Balance are always near 100%. The documentation seems to say this is tied to throughput credits, but I don't understand why EBS Byte balance is the only thing affected.

When EBS Byte balance drops to 0 my website slows to a crawl.

I'm running a load balanced Django/Python web app. 5000-7000 page views a day. It has endpoints that receive upload from users in the 3-4mb range. I get about 20-30 of those uploads a day

[monitoring metrics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eEz4D.png)

[storage settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3l1L.png)

[full metrics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xF8js.png)

I've tried increasing the allocated storage twice but it had no effect. The only post I see with a similar problem says they increase to 1000 GiB storage but it didn't help. Is that what I should try?

Comment: "The documentation seems to say"  Please link to that documentation.

Comment: Here is the documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/rds-metrics.html Search for ebs byte balance

Comment: The burst balance is about the disk's ability to handle I/O bytes, while the byte balance is about the instance's capacity to send and receive data to the disk over the network.  (EBS is, simplistically stated, network-attached storage).  What do your `NetworkReceiveThroughput` and `NetworkTransmitThroughput` metrics look like, and does one or the other (or both) of them correlate to the byte balance metric?  Does the amount of data seem reasonable to you?

Comment: This isn't definitive, but I would interpret it to mean you are doing a lot of sequential scans of large tables (likely due to inadequate indexing) and that through the magic of readahead consolidation, each IO requests reads a lot of bytes.  So you are using all your byte throughput, despite having a low count of raw IO requests.

Comment: I ended up just going to a t4g.medium instance. I checked my most common queries and there were not a bunch of seq changes, I appeared to have good index coverage/usage.

Comment: I believe this was tied to using a Multi-AZ deployment. If it's maintaining a synchronous read replica I image that would have it reading and sending a lot more data.